# Check read/write permission to Google Fusion Table

Tags: sql, qt, google-fusion-tables, google-drive-api

I am interfacing with one of my Google Fusion Tables in a C++/Qt program using the [GFT API](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/using) and the [access token authentication method](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2). Read access to the table is restricted to users on my company's domain, and write access is restricted even further to a handful of users.

I therefore have three levels of authentication:

1. User has read/write access (available SQL: SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE)
2. User has read-only access (available SQL: SELECT)
3. User has no access (available SQL: none)

I would like my program's interface to change based on the user's authentication level. I have figured out that I get a 403 HTTP error when the user attempts to SELECT or UPDATE without the proper permissions, but I'd like to nip that in the bud without any alarming 403 errors.

**The question:**
Is it possible to check the GFT token's authentication level before attempting an actual query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the [Drive permissions API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions) to find out what a user can do with the table.